# How to create new canvas at photoshop and apply a layer by layer name?

Tags: photoshop, layer, photoshop-script

How to create new canvas at Photoshop and apply a layer by layer name ?

So simple what i want is

```
Create a new canvas certain size such as 150x40
Apply a layer to that canvas. Select layer by its name
```

How can i do that these 2 simple things with Photoshop scripting

CS6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Photoshop Javascript Reference](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/photoshop/pdfs/cs6/Photoshop-CS6-JavaScript-Ref.pdf)

I believe you're looking for `documents.add()` and `Layers.getByName()`.